# qt pro file: QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS questions

Tags: qt

I have a code:

```
copydata.commands = $(COPY_DIR) \"$$shell_path($$PWD/qml)\" \"$$shell_path($$OUT_PWD/qml)\"
first.depends = $(first) copydata
export(first.depends)
export(copydata.commands)
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first copydata
```

I've read `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS` docs and did not see such things in examples. What is `export`? Why is it required here? Why is `first` target required here too?

Why can't I just use this code? Why does not it work?

```
copydata.commands = $(COPY_DIR) \"$$shell_path($$PWD/qml)\" \"$$shell_path($$OUT_PWD/qml)\"
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copydata
```